# How to use XQuery to create a DOT graph?

Tags: xml, xquery, dot

I need to create a DOT graph on the basis of the following XML:

```
<layout-structure>
    <layout-root id="layout-root">
        <layout-chunk id="header-text">
            <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.01"/>
            <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.02"/>
        </layout-chunk>
        <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.03"/>
    </layout-root>
</layout-structure>
```

I want to use DOT to visualize the dependencies between the different **layout-chunk** and **layout-leaf** elements, which are identified using either *id* or *xref* attributes, depending on the element type.

The result I want is given below in DOT:

```
graph "layout-root" {
"layout-root" -- "header-text";
"header-text" -- "lay-1.01";
"header-text" -- "lay-1.02";
"layout-root" -- "lay-1.03";
}
```

Which would result in this visualized graph:

[image]

What would be the best way to use XQuery to parse **layout-root** element for **layout-chunk** and **layout-structure** elements and their possible children, and returning the *id* and *xref* attributes to be used in the DOT graph?

I am a complete newbie in XQuery and have tried various approaches; I think I need to concatenate the *id* and *xref* values in each element, in order to produce the required markup for DOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query may help (tested with BaseX and Saxon):

```
declare variable $nl := '&#10;';

declare function local:ref($root) {
  string-join((
    for $c in $root/layout-chunk
    return (
      concat('  "', $root/@id, '" -- "', $c/@id, '";', $nl),
      local:ref($c)
    ),
    local:leaf($root)), "")
};

declare function local:leaf($root) {
  for $c in $root/layout-leaf
  return concat('  "', $root/@id, '" -- "', $c/@xref, '";', $nl)
};

(: Alternative: let $doc := doc("doc.xml") :)
let $doc := document {
  <layout-structure>
      <layout-root id="layout-root">
          <layout-chunk id="header-text">
              <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.01"/>
              <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.02"/>
          </layout-chunk>
          <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.03"/>
      </layout-root>
  </layout-structure> }
let $root := $doc/layout-structure/*
return concat(
  'graph "', $root/name(), '" { ' , $nl,
  local:ref($root),
'}')
```

Comment: Many thanks, @christian-grun!

I get most of the code, but could you walk me through this part in the second function declaration:

    `return (
    concat('  "', $root/@id, '" -- "', $c/@id, '";', $nl),
      local:ref($c)
    ),
    local:leaf($root)), "")
    };`

What exactly does the code do after the concat function?

Comment: Don’t know where to start… What is it exactly you need to understand?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out after reading a bit on the function definitions - it was a new thing to me! Still, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an XML syntax for Dot, called DotML. I have found that generating DotML is easier than generating Dot directly. Details are here:

http://martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/